# How can I create a static portfolio on Shopify and avoid 404 errors?

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-template

I am currently trying to create a static portfolio for myself on Shopify. However, I am facing an issue with keeping all the content within the theme itself. My goal is to have specific content for pages such as "contact", "portfolio", and "services" all within the theme. So, when I visit robrics.me/pages/contact or robrics.me/pages/portfolio, the relevant content from inside the theme should be displayed. However, what currently happens is that a 404 page shows up instead.

I setup sections for each page and also setup if else statements to show content from sections only those specific pages eg if contact elseif portfolio etc. etc.

how can I achieve those things via liquid, I don't want to use JavaScript for this but if there is no solution I might opt for it

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to improve this setup

Comment: simply use separate templates for pages and use theme sections to store data.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let me simplify this for you

1. Go to the "templates" section of your theme and locate the "page.liquid" file.
2. Either delete the file or remove its content.
3. To display different content for different pages, you can use the following code in your theme.liquid file:

```html
    {% if canonical_url contains 'contact' %}
    {% section 'contact' %}
    {% elsif canonical_url contains 'services' %}
    {% section 'services' %}
    {% endif %}
```

This will check the URL of the page and accordingly display the content from either the contact or services section or snippet.

4. However, if you try to access a page that doesn't exist, such as robrics.me/pages/contact, it will show a 404 page error.
5. To prevent this, you can go to your dashboard, click on "Online store" and then "Pages". From there, you can create a blank page with the title of the page you want to display, such as "contact" or "services". This will ensure that when the user visits the specified URL, the content stored within the appropriate section or snippet will be displayed instead of a 404 error.

Hope this helps!